Distribution of Sum of Bernoullis with Specified Covariances
I have a some $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables $X_{12},...,X_{(n-1)n}$ with the following dependence structure. $X_{ij}$ and $X_{kl}$ are independent if $i,j,k,l$ are all distinct, but $Cov(X_{ij},X_{ik}) = Cov(X_{ij}, X_{jk}) = \alpha$ (which is known). I want to compute the distribution of $S = \sum_{1\leq i<j \leq n} X_{ij}$. Clearly if all the vairiables were dependent then I would just use a binomial. I have also looked through the reference Sums of Possibly Associated Bernoulli Random Variables, but I can only find solutions for this when the covariance is the same for all of the variables. Is there a standard distribution for something of this kind? I've also tried simulating the variables, but I can't find a good match to any of the 'standard' distributions we might expect, e.g. Gaussian, Additive Binomial, Conway-Maxwell Binomial etc. Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I'm a little slow:  Do you have ${n}\choose{2}$ random variables for a specific value of $n$?  For example, if $n=5$, then are the random variables $X_{12},X_{13},X_{14},X_{15},X_{23},X_{24},X_{25},X_{34},X_{35}$, and $X_{45}$?  Also, is $E(X_{ij})=p$ for all of those random variables?

Assuming that when $n=3$ the Bernoulli random variables are $X_{12},X_{13}$, and $X_{23}$, there are 8 possible outcomes:  000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, and 111.  If we can determine the probabilities of those outcomes with the means, variances, and covariances that you require, then the distribution of the sum can be determined or at least there is a process to determine what we can know about that distribution.
Using Mathematica to do the algebra we can equate the means, variances, and covariances to functions of the probabilities of the 8 possible outcomes.  (And I've used $a$ in place of $\alpha$.)
(* Means *)
m12 = p == q100 + q101 + q110 + q111;
m13 = p == q010 + q011 + q110 + q111;
m23 = p == q001 + q011 + q101 + q111;

(* Variances *)
v12 = (1 - p)  p == (0 - p)^2  (q000 + q001 + q010 + q011) + 
      (1 - p)^2  (q100 + q101 + q110 + q111);
v13 = (1 - p)  p == (0 - p)^2  (q000 + q001 + q100 + q101) +
      (1 - p)^2  (q010 + q011 + q110 + q111);
v23 = (1 - p)  p == (0 - p)^2  (q000 + q010 + q100 + q110) + 
      (1 - p)^2  (q001 + q011 + q101 + q111);

(* Covariances *)
cov1213 = a == (0 - p) (0 - p) (q000 + q001) + (1 - p) (0 - p) (q010 + q011) +
  (0 - p) (1 - p) (q100 + q101) + (0 - p) (1 - p) (q110 + q111);
cov1223 = a == (0 - p) (0 - p) (q000 + q010) + (1 - p) (0 - p) (q001 + q011) + 
  (0 - p) (1 - p) (q100 + q110) + (0 - p) (1 - p) (q101 + q111);
cov1323 = a == (0 - p) (0 - p) (q000 + q100) + (1 - p) (0 - p) (q001 + q101) +
  (0 - p) (1 - p) (q010 + q110) + (0 - p) (1 - p) (q011 + q111);

sol = Solve[{total, m12, m13, m23, v12, v13, v23, cov1213, cov1223, cov1323},
  {q000, q001, q010, q011, q100, q101, q110, q111}][[1]]
(* {q000 -> -((-a - p + p^2)/p) - q001, q010 -> q001, q011 -> -(a/p) - q001,
    q100 -> q001, q101 -> -(a/p) - q001, q110 -> -(a/p) - q001, 
    q111 -> -((-2 a - p^2)/p) + q001} *)

Unless I've missed some additional restriction, knowing the means, variances, and covariances does not fully determine the distribution.  In addition, there will be restrictions on the potential values of $a$ given values of $p$ and the probability of one of the outcomes (which Mathematica chose to be $q_{001}$).
The probability that the desired sum is zero is  $-((-a - p + p^2)/p) - q_{001}$.  The probability that the desired sum is 1, 2, or 3 can also be determined.  Is this what you had in mind or am I missing something in the definition of the dependence structure of the Bernoulli random variables?
